# Exists a function f continuous at a point x which is a limit point of points at which f is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Is there a function *f* defined on all real numbers that is continuous at x and not continuous at a set of points in the domain having x as a limit point?

I have determined that we want *f* at x. We want p(n)-> x, but we do not want f continuous at p(n). Also, any domain has domain of all real numbers.

After countless practice trying to interpret this question, I am unsure if it is true or false.

I believe this definition is crucial with this problem: We say that a function *f* is **continuous** at the point x if and only if for every sequence p1, p2, p3,... in the domain of *f* converging to x we have that *f*(p1), *f*(p2), *f*(p3),... converges to *f*(x).

Any help on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)$, that is, $f(x) = x $ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise.  It is continuous only at $0$.